# Hadoop mapReduce How to store only values in HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am using This for removing Duplicate lines

```
public class DLines
 {
   public static class TokenCounterMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>
    {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
      private Text word = new Text();
      @Override
      public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
       {
           String line=value.toString();
           //int hash_code=line.hashCode();
           context.write(value, one);
       }
   }

public static class TokenCounterReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> 
 {
        @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException 
     {
 public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException 
     {
       int sum = 0;
       for (IntWritable value : values) 
       {   
           sum += value.get();        
       }
       if (sum<2)
           {
             context.write(key,new IntWritable(sum));
           }
      }
      }
```

i have to store only Key in hdfs.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not require value from your reducer, just use [NullWritable](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/NullWritable.html).

You could simply say `context.write(key,NullWritable.get());`

In you driver, you could also set

```
 job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
 job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
```

&

```
 job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
 job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
```

Comment: Any code changes, when combiner is used with above code. Getting error for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `NullWritable` class.

```
public class DLines
 {
   public static class TokenCounterMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>
    {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
      private Text word = new Text();
      @Override
      public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
       {
           String line=value.toString();
           context.write(value, one);
       }
   }

public static class TokenCounterReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, NullWritable> 
 {
   NullWritable out = NullWritable.get();
        @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException 
       {
       int sum = 0;
       for (IntWritable value : values) 
       {   
           sum += value.get();        
       }
       if (sum<2)
           {
             context.write(key,out);
           }
      }
      }
```

**Driver code**

```
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I tried the same way, its working fine.. But when I use combiner I am getting error as
            java.io.IOException: wrong value class: class org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable is not class org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable

Comment: @Abhinay: You cannot make use of combiners in this case.Combiners are mini reducers whose operation is commutative and associative and combiner's signature should match Reducers.If combiner signature is "<Text, IntWritable, Text, NullWritable> ", you will get error as reducer input key and value are --Text and IntWritable,but combiners's output key and value class is Text,NullWritable