# MapReduce IOException

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, ioexception

I write such code for MapReduce text sorting:

```
public static class SortMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {
    private Text citizenship = new Text();

    @Override
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        citizenship.set(value.toString().split(",")[11]);
        context.write(citizenship, value);
    }
}

public static class PrintReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, NullWritable, Text> {

    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Iterator<Text> valIt = values.iterator();

        while (valIt.hasNext()) {
            Text value = valIt.next();
            context.write(NullWritable.get(), value);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Football Sort");
    job.setJarByClass(FootballSort.class);
    job.setMapperClass(SortMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(PrintReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(PrintReducer.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

but it always catch

> IOException in lines 26, 34
>   reason: class org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable is not class org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

Answer (score 0):

your `mapper outputformat` is not match your code   ,In your main method   you set the output  TEXT

```
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
```

but  in your mapper `public static class PrintReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, NullWritable, Text>` your  set them `NullWritable  TEXT`

Comment: But I need reduce output only value - without key. Like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23601380/hadoop-mapreduce-how-to-store-only-values-in-hdfs described

Comment: My mapper output sets as Text, Text:     
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
//
My reducer (job) output sets as NullWritable, Text:  
job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

Comment: the map output keyCan not be null, if it is null will make the map output and reduce the input does not match and cause the program to run error.

Answer (score 0):

@Abhinay: You cannot make use of combiners in this case.Combiners are mini reducers whose operation is commutative and associative and combiner's signature should match Reducers.If combiner signature is " ", you will get error as reducer input key and value are --Text and IntWritable,but combiners's output key and value class is Text,NullWritable – Unmesha SreeVeni Dec 28 '15 at 5:51

//job.setCombinerClass(PrintReducer.class); or delete this string is way to fix